# Align textfield cursor caret to always be aligned to middle

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, alignment

I have a textfield which is aligned middle with a placeholder.

If I click on it, the carrot starts on the left of the placeholder.

Is there a way to have it always start in the middle so as I type, the characters are being pushed outwards versus from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the value of the `textAlignment` property to be `NSTextAlignmentCenter` and you should get the result you're looking for.